# records for the model grouped by the relationship with the other model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

I have a model with a one to many relationship and I want to see all records for the model grouped by the relationship.

For example, I want to output something like this:

One [1]

- Many [1]
- Many [2]
- Many [3]

One [2]

- Many [4]
- Many [5]
- Many [6]

so far with the code given below I can get as far as:

One [1]

- Many [1]
- Many [2]
- Many [3]

One [2]

- Many [1]
- Many [2]
- Many [3]

MODEL

```
class Many extends Model
{
    public function ones()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\One');
    }
}

class One extends Model
{  
    public function manys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Many');
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
class YeargroupController extends Controller
{
     public function index() 
    { 
        $one = One::get();
        $ones = One::find(1)->manys;
    }}
```

VIEWS

```
</div>@foreach ($ones as $row)
        <div class="card-body">{{$row->name}}
            <div class="row">@foreach ($one as $row)
               {{$row->name}}
                </div>@endforeach 
            </div>
        </div>   @endforeach
```

How do I access the relationships for the next One record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YeargroupController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    { 
        return view(..., [
            // get all the 'ones' with their relationship loaded
            'ones' => One::with('manys')->get(),
        ]);
    }
}

{{-- iterate each one --}}
@foreach ($ones as $one)
    {{-- iterate the manys of the one --}}
    @foreach ($one->manys as $many)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```